# How to fire global actions from a within a Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, utility-bar

Is this feature available? Is there an API I can use?

I know you have the Utility BarAPI (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:utilityBarAPI/documentation) which allows you to utilize a dock component and Quick ActionAPI (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:quickActionAPI/documentation) allows you to open the lightning default modal.

Ultimately I want the effect that a global action has which is:
Slide up from bottom right!
Open multiple global actions at a time and have them side by side.

Comment: Can you attach wire-frame to the question, it is hard to visualize what you are thinking.